# AWS EC2 - Automatic AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, server, devops

I have a AWS EC2 instance That i need to manually access to the AWS console and make a daily image of the machine(AMI)

How i can make a daily AMI backup of the machine and delete old version (old then 7 days)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything that you can do through the web console you can also do through the CLI.

In this particular case, I suspect a combination of [aws ec2 create-image](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/create-image.html), [aws ec2 describe-images](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-images.html), and [aws ec2 deregister-image](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/deregister-image.html) would let you do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

AWS lambda would be a right solution to automate the backup of your ami and clean up. You can schedule the lambda function (basically a python code) to run periodically. This way you don't need to have your ec2 running all the time. An example here http://powerupcloud.azurewebsites.net/2016/10/15/serverless-automate-ami-creation-and-deletion-using-aws-lambda/

Answer (score 0):

Below is a shell script I use that runs daily via cron. You can set the value of a variable prevday1 to set how long you want to keep your images. In your case you want 7 days to it would be

`prevday1=$(date --date="7 days ago" +%Y-%m-%d)`

Here is the full script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# prior to using this script you will need to install the aws cli on the local machine

# https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/setup-aws-cli.html

# AWS CLI - will need to configure this
# sudo apt-get -y install awscli 
# example of current config - july 10, 2020
#aws configure
#aws configure set key ARIAW5YUMJT7PO2N7L *fake - user your own*
#aws configure secret X2If+xa/rFITQVMrgdQVpFLx1c7fwP604QkH/x *fake - user your own*
#aws configure set region us-east-2
#aws configure set format json



# backup EC2 instances nightly 4:30 am GMT
# 30 4 * * * . $HOME/.profile;  /var/www/devopstools/shell-scripts/file_backup_scripts/ec2_backup.sh

script_dir="$(dirname "$0")"

# If you want live notifications about backups
#SLACK_API_URL="https://hooks.slack.com/services/T6VQ93KM/BT8REK5/hFYEDUCoO1Bw72wxxFSj7oY"

source "$script_dir/includes/helpers.sh"

prevday1=$(date --date="2 days ago" +%Y-%m-%d)
prevday2=$(date --date="3 days ago" +%Y-%m-%d)
today=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")

instances=()
# add as many instances to backup as needed
instances+=("autobackup_impressto|i-0ed78a1f3583e1859")


for ((i = 0; i < ${#instances[@]}; i++)); do

    instance=${instances[$i]}

    instanceName="$(cut -d'|' -f1 <<<"$instance")"
    instanceId="$(cut -d'|' -f2 <<<"$instance")"

    prevImageName1="${instanceName}_${prevday1}_$instanceId"
    prevImageName2="${instanceName}_${prevday2}_$instanceId"
    newImageName="${instanceName}_${today}_$instanceId"

    consoleout --green "Begin backing $instanceName [$instanceId]"

    aws ec2 create-image \
        --instance-id $instanceId \
        --name "$newImageName" \
        --description "$instanceName" \
        --no-reboot

    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "$newImageName created."
        echo ""
        if [ ! -z "${SLACK_API_URL}" ]; then
            curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data '{"text":":rotating_light: Backing up *'$newImageName'* to AMI. :rotating_light:"}' ${SLACK_API_URL}        fi 
        echo -e "\e[92mBacking up ${newImageName} to AMI."
    else
        echo "$newImageName not created."
        echo ""
    fi

    imageId=$(aws ec2 describe-images --filters "Name=name,Values=${prevImageName1}" --query 'Images[*].[ImageId]' --output text)

    if [ ! -z "${imageId}" ]; then

        echo "Deregistering ${prevImageName1} [${imageId}]"
        echo ""
        echo "aws ec2 deregister-image --image-id ${imageId}"
        aws ec2 deregister-image --image-id ${imageId}
    fi

    imageId=$(aws ec2 describe-images --filters "Name=name,Values=${prevImageName2}" --query 'Images[*].[ImageId]' --output text)

    if [ ! -z "${imageId}" ]; then

        echo "Deregistering ${prevImageName2} [${imageId}]"
        echo ""
        echo "aws ec2 deregister-image --image-id ${imageId}"
        aws ec2 deregister-image --image-id ${imagesId}
    fi

    consoleout --green "Completed backing $instanceName"

done
```

Also available here - https://impressto.net/automatic-aws-ec2-backups/

Answer (score -2):

You can use https://github.com/alestic/ec2-consistent-snapshot and run it in a cron job. It supports various filesystems and has support for ensuring database snapshots are consistent. If you don't have a database in your instance, it will still ensure consistent snapshots by freezing the filesystem.